How to speed up sequence insert in oracle
I have a table with about 5 million records. At specific day,  we transfer these records from source table to target table. The only column difference is that target table has a sequence column. For this I have created a sequence with a cache of 10000. Insert query would be like this:
insert into target select seq_name.nextval, * from source;

With sequence added, the above statement takes 2 minutes to complete. I have tried couple of other ways, like first adding the record to target table & then updating sequence or using merge to update sequence later. But it always take more time.
Is there any other way to increase the performance of the insert query?
Edit1: Adding my create table sample script:
CREATE TABLE APPL.SM_TEST_TEST
(
  SOMECOLUMN  VARCHAR2(200 CHAR),
  SOMEID      INTEGER
)
NOLOGGING 
PARALLEL (DEGREE 8) 
RESULT_CACHE (MODE DEFAULT)
PCTFREE 0     
PCTUSED 99 
INITRANS 16 
STORAGE (
   INITIAL 500M
   NEXT 500M 
   MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
)
COMPRESS FOR DIRECT_LOAD OPERATIONS 
NOCACHE 
MONITORING 


If a sequence is taking up time, then either

the cache size is too small for such a load, or
you are on an older release, because in later versions of 19c, we automatically will bump up the cache size under load

Sequences should add zero overhead to your loads. You mentioned a cache of 10,000 which should be ample, so I suspect its not the sequence. Try running a trace on the session (or lock at v$active_session_history) to see where the time is being lost.
Here's an example from my laptop giving a rough idea of the kind of throughput you should expect on an unindexed table
SQL> desc src
 Name                                                                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- -------------------------------
 OWNER                                                                            VARCHAR2(128)
 OBJECT_NAME                                                                      VARCHAR2(128)
 SUBOBJECT_NAME                                                                   VARCHAR2(128)
 OBJECT_ID                                                                        NUMBER
 DATA_OBJECT_ID                                                                   NUMBER
 OBJECT_TYPE                                                                      VARCHAR2(23)
 CREATED                                                                          DATE
 LAST_DDL_TIME                                                                    DATE
 TIMESTAMP                                                                        VARCHAR2(19)
 STATUS                                                                           VARCHAR2(7)
 TEMPORARY                                                                        VARCHAR2(1)
 GENERATED                                                                        VARCHAR2(1)
 SECONDARY                                                                        VARCHAR2(1)
 NAMESPACE                                                                        NUMBER
 EDITION_NAME                                                                     VARCHAR2(128)
 SHARING                                                                          VARCHAR2(18)
 EDITIONABLE                                                                      VARCHAR2(1)
 ORACLE_MAINTAINED                                                                VARCHAR2(1)
 APPLICATION                                                                      VARCHAR2(1)
 DEFAULT_COLLATION                                                                VARCHAR2(100)
 DUPLICATED                                                                       VARCHAR2(1)
 SHARDED                                                                          VARCHAR2(1)
 IMPORTED_OBJECT                                                                  VARCHAR2(1)
 CREATED_APPID                                                                    NUMBER
 CREATED_VSNID                                                                    NUMBER
 MODIFIED_APPID                                                                   NUMBER
 MODIFIED_VSNID                                                                   NUMBER

SQL> select num_rows, blocks
  2  from user_tables
  3  where table_name = 'SRC';

  NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- ----------
   5427666     111956

SQL> create sequence seq cache 10000;

Sequence created.

SQL> insert into tgt
  2  select seq.nextval, s.* from src s;

5427666 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:10.70
SQL>

If you're not getting that, then a trace should reveal where the time is being lost

This is my oracle version - "Oracle Database 19c EE Extreme Perf Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production". I did some research which tell me to increase cache size, currently set to 10000. I tried the query with & without sequence & the one with took 2 minutes. I will try to see if I can find anything in trace.

do select banner_full from v$version to see the patch number.  19.12 or above. Full details here https://connor-mcdonald.com/2021/08/06/we-killed-sequence-contention/

How about
insert into target
select ROWNUM, s.* from source s;

Then, if you'll add some more rows into it, create a sequence which starts with (currently) MAX + 1 value of the sequence column.
Also, you'd rather specify columns you're selecting into and fetching from, don't use * wildcard because of the best practice.

yes, I've specified column names & not using star.
How rownum would help me to keep sequence column in target table? every batch I insert will start from 1 right?

Yes, every new INSERT that uses ROWNUM will start from 1 which means that you'll get duplicates; you probably don't want them, right? If so, perhaps you could include additional column, for example BATCH_NUMBER (it would have the same value for every batch) or BATCH_DATE (dd.mm.yyyy) so that combination of e.g. [BATCH_NUMBER, SEQUENCE_NUMBER] is unique. Or, as you already know, use an ordinary sequence (as your current query).

The point here @Visha is in case when there is only one process adding rows to a table you do not need a sequence. Use simple (select max(id) from target) + rownum. Sequence shine when there are many concurrent session inserting in the table. But as other said their overhead is low, your problem would be somewhere else..

A sequence is not a perf constraint if properly configured. Having to do a separate select on the table to get the maximum value - and hold a lock on the entire table in the meantime to prevent anyone from adding yet another value after that max query and before you're done and your insert is committed, is more unwieldy, less concurrent (or less safe) than simply a sequence or identity column (which is also a sequence). Totally agree on * being a bad practice.

@PaulW you distinctly miss the precondition - there is only one process adding rows to a table - you may lock the table exclusive - there will be nobody prevented;)

@MarmiteBomber, I see no such affirmation by OP that that constraint applies to his situation, and Littlefoot's answer doesn't call this constraint out either. A reader of this discussion should be alerted to the downsides of using ROWNUM vs. a sequence, hence my comment. Further, it's not a good practice to assume that what today may be a single non-overlapping job will always and ever be so. Stronger code will write in protection against future possibilities before they happen, which means preferring sequences over ROWNUM.

You are completely right @PaulW and my comment is valid only under the premise mentioned above. Also is true that some actions aimed as protection against future possibilities did cause immediate problems even though the anticipated possibilities did not appear in the future at all.

At a cache size of 10,000 unless you are using RAC with a sequence that has the ORDERED clause (not a good combination), the sequence is likely not your problem. A cached lookup of the sequence object every 10,000 records would mean 5mil/10k = 500 lookups, which is going to takes no more than couple seconds at most. Not your issue.
Ensure you are using a direct path load by adding the append hint:
insert /*+ append */ into target select seq_name.nextval, * from source;

For even more speed, leverage parallelism by enabling parallel dml:
insert /*+ append enable_parallel_dml parallel(8) */ into target select seq_name.nextval, * from source;

Or:
alter session enable parallel dml;

insert /*+ append parallel(8) */ into target select seq_name.nextval, * from source;

Make sure you have no triggers on the table or foreign keys. If you do, those will not only disable parallel DML but are also likely the main contributors to the slow inserts. Also you want to minimize indexes - the more indexes, the more work to build them out on load.
On the off chance that you are using RAC and your sequence includes the ORDERED clause, remove the ORDERED clause (recreate the sequence without it). You don't need that ordering to be enforced and it really adds a lot of concurrency problems when in RAC.

I have added my create table script in the question for reference & I use append & parallel hint on insert. Do I still need to added alter session statement?

@Visha, it's the actual INSERT statement we need to see - exactly as you employ it
